# Swagger API authentication with laravel-passport

Tags: php, laravel, swagger, laravel-passport

I am using swagger for the documentation of an API application built using Laravel 5.8. I am also using Passport for the API authentication and tried implementing it in the documentation.

When I try to authorize a user on swagger, I get the error here

> auth errorTypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Here's how I have set it up swagger up

In `l5-swagger.php` config file

```
/* Open API 3.0 support */
'passport' => [ // Unique name of security
    'type' => 'oauth2', // The type of the security scheme. Valid values are "basic", "apiKey" or "oauth2".
    'description' => 'Laravel passport oauth2 security.',
    'in' => 'header',
    'scheme' => 'https',
    'flows' => [
        "password" => [
            "authorizationUrl" => config('app.url') . '/oauth/authorize',
            "tokenUrl" => config('app.url') . '/oauth/token',
            "refreshUrl" => config('app.url') . '/token/refresh',
            "scopes" => []
        ],
    ],
],
```

In the controller I have the swagger code

```
/**
* @OA\Get(
*      path="/products/{product}",
*      tags={"Product"},
*      description="Gets specified product",
*      operationId="getProductById",
*      summary="Fetches a product by the product Id",
*      security={{"passport": {}}},
*      @OA\Parameter(...),
*      @OA\Response(...),
* )
*/
```

This is the image of swagger authorization screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiYjs.png

I get the `client_id` & `client_secret` from the `oauth_clients` table.

How is the authentication done and what am I doing differently?

Comment: What is the error message on the Console tab of browser dev tools?

Comment: Just a warning `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/oauth/token. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)`. Though I have cors enabled for the project and web and mobile are able to connect successfully

Comment: What host and port is Swagger UI running on? If you run `curl -X OPTIONS http://localhost/oauth/token --verbose`, does the response has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

Comment: It's running on Bluehost VPS on port 80. The response doesn't have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

Comment: Looks like CORS is not set up properly.